# When user signs out from SAML Service provider, it does not logs out user from the Salesforce Identity provider

Tags: salesforce, single-sign-on, simplesamlphp

I am doing SSO between Salesforce and Drupal using Salesforce as Identity provider and Drupal as Service provider using SimpleSAMLPHP. When user signs out from the Drupal web site, it is not getting logged out from the Salesforce.

To solve the issue, I used 'SingleLogoutService' as https://salescloud--OptusFull.cs13.my.salesforce.com/secur/logout.jsp in Drupal Service provider. But the issue here is that the log out process now ends up with Salesforce login page and I did not find a way to redirect it to the Drupal site. Is there any way to redirect user back to Drupal site.

Please find the metadata information from metadata/saml20-idp-remote.php

```
    $metadata['https://salescloud--OptusFull.cs13.my.salesforce.com'] = array (
      'entityid' => 'https://salescloud--OptusFull.cs13.my.salesforce.com',
      'contacts' =>
      array (
      ),
      'metadata-set' => 'saml20-idp-remote',
      'expire' => 1739182548,
      'SingleSignOnService' =>
      array (
        0 =>
        array (
          'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
          'Location' => 'https://salescloud--OptusFull.cs13.my.salesforce.com/idp/endpoint/HttpPost',
        ),
        1 =>
        array (
          'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
          'Location' => 'https://salescloud--OptusFull.cs13.my.salesforce.com/idp/endpoint/HttpRedirect',
        ),
      ),
     'SingleLogoutService' => 'https://salescloud--OptusFull.cs13.my.salesforce.com/secur/logout.jsp',
       'ArtifactResolutionService' =>
      array (
      ),
      'keys' =>
      array (
        0 =>
        array (
          'encryption' => false,
          'signing' => true,
          'type' => 'X509Certificate',
          'X509Certificate' => 'MIIErDCCA.....',
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a setting in Salesforce that controls the page where the user lands after logout via the identity provider. The setting is under Security Controls > Single Sign-On Settings ->  - Identity Provider Logout URL . This setting will only appear in your SF production org if you have My Domain turned on.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce does not support Single Logout Service 
(Initiated or not in the IdP).

If you set as SingleLogoutService the Salesforce normal logout service, you will end at the Salesforce login page and not LogoutResponse will be sent to the SP(drupal). Also, if you directly Logout from Salesforce, no LogoutRequest will be sent to the SP(drupal).